# Accesser is not working in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am working on crud field = "select2_from_ajax" in backpack,
already defined ACCESSORS in my model but it's not working...

### :: MODEL ::

```
protected $appends = ['countystate'];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

public function getCountystateAttribute()
{
    return $this->name . '(' . $this->state_name . ')';
}
```

### :: CONTROLLER ::

```
 CRUD::field([
    'label'     => "County",
    'type'      => 'select2_from_ajax',
    'name'      => 'county',
    'entity'    => 'counties',
    'attribute' => 'countystate',
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'dependencies' => ['state'],
    'data_source' => url("api/county"),
    'placeholder' => "Select a county",
    'include_all_form_fields' => true,
    'tab' => 'Information',
]);
```

:: API ::

```
class CountyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search_term = $request->input('q');
        $form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');

        // if no state has been selected, show no options
        if (! $form['state']) {
            return [];
        }

        if ($form['state']) {
            $state_name = State::where('id', '=', $form['state'])->first();
            $state_name = $state_name->name;
        }

        if ($search_term!="" && $state_name != ""){
            $results = County::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_term.'%')->where('state_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$state_name.'%')->orderby('name','ASC')->paginate(10);
        }else{
            $results = County::paginate(10);
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

and after this i got this result...

[image]

All ajax's loaded at a time, and selection is empty...

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your dropdown filled with county values, you need to have this endpoint: `url("api/county")` working. And for this you need to create the route and method [as the docs state](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-fields#select2_from_ajax-pro), OR, to use the [fetch API](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operation-fetch)

I highly recommend you to use the Fetch API.

```php
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;

protected function fetchCounty()
{
    return $this->fetch(\App\Models\County::class);
}
```

The new endpoint is; `backpack_url('yourmodel/fetch/county')`

If your data do not come from a Model, but from somewhere else, you can customize this method to your needs.

Comment: Yes, All the data comes through API.. and it's works perfectly but when i use an accessor then i don't know why but data is not displayed...

Comment: @VatsalPatel in your case, `countystate` should be in the appends, as it is apparently  Can you check if the `countystate` is returned in the API?